# If I make changes in the UI in wordpress how can I find the file that has changed?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I have an intern working on a wordpress application that Im trying to deploy with docker.
I dont want to include the whole wordpress application because it involves committing it to gitlab, so only want to track the relevant files that have changed.

Case in point. He has added menu items but they are not shown when the docker container runs so we are missing the files that have been changed when he edits via the UI.

**How can I find the corresponding file when changes are made via the UI?**

The whole `wp-content` folder and the `database` have been included with the conatiner.

Comment: Everything changed by the intern should be in wp-content. Adding menu items is usuallly done by code in the theme's functions.php or plugin

Comment: Hes not that familiar with code so hes been doing all the editing and configuration via `site_address/wp-admin` and the theme is being included, most of the changes have taken effect but the menu items and the logo have not

Comment: That's bad. You will lose his changes on following WordPress updates. The proper way to add menus in the WordPress dashboard is by using [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/).

Comment: Or do you mean that there's an interface in the dashboard that he is using? Then his settings are stored in the database.

Comment: Theres an admin GUI/dashboard that a wordpress installation has. He is using that.

Comment: The settings is being saved somewhere in the database then.